# Writing a numpy array in bytes format in python and reading in C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I am converting numpy array to bytes and writing to a file using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
f=open("myfile","wb")
mydata=np.array([1,2,3,600])
bina = mydata.tobytes()
print(bina)
f.write(bina)
f.close()
```

Then, I read this file in C++,using the following code:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
using namespace std;
std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData = readFile("myfile");
}
```

I am not able to generate my original data [1,2,3,600] back in C++. What should I do?

Comment: What result are you getting? `600` is more than `unsigned char` can fit.

Comment: Before I am writing the array to a file in python. I am converting the '600' to bytes. So, reading in C++ using unsigned char might be okay.

Comment: Yes, but `unsigned char` can only store numbers between `0` and `255`. `600` will not fit.

Answer (score 2):

You must decide an element size (32 or 64 bits for the element) and use the same on both side. Ideally you should also decide an endianness but I assume that you will use same system so will have same endianness. Let us say we use 32 bits:

Python side:

```
import numpy as np
f=open("myfile","wb")
mydata=np.array([1,2,3,600], dtype='int32')
bina = mydata.tobytes()
print(bina)
f.write(bina)
f.close()
```

C++ side:

```
using namespace std;
std::vector<int32_t> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<int32_t> fileData(fileSize/sizeof(int32_t));
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int32_t> fileData = readFile("myfile");
}
```

Comment: My aim is to compress the data which I wrote in a file (using python). I wish to read the data in bytes in C++ for performing the compression. So, the original code is correct for this, right?

Comment: @nivedita: if what you want is not what you show, I cannot help you... As 600 cannot fit in a single byte, I assumed that you were transfering integer values.

Comment: I wrote a simple version of the code, so that everyone can easily understand it. Additionally, I am transferring integer values (by converting them to bytes).

Comment: @nivedita: I did not intend to be offensive, and I sincerily apologize if you felt my comment offensive. What I meant is that if you tranfer integer values, then you should use int32 dtype arrays Python side and `vector<int32_t>` C++ side, but if you transfer a compressed byte array, then you should read it as a `vector<uchar>` (or `vector<BYTE>`) and uncompress the resulting array C++ side with the same compression algo.